# "Plugging in X" vs. "plugging X in"

Tags: prepositions, word-order, phrasal-verbs, particle-shift

Does one say

> Plugging in that value into the previous equation...

or

> Plugging that value in the previous equation...

or something else?

Comment: pluggin in into is for sure wrong - if you remove the _in_ in the first sentence I think you will be fine

Comment: What happened to good old "substitute"?

Comment: Well... I have used "substitute" many times in my text. Therefore I have sometimes decided to plug in "plug in" instead of "substitute" ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A combination of your two examples would be correct:

*Plugging that value into the previous equation..*

In this sentence you are dealing with the phrasal verb '**plug in**', which has then been split by the noun ('that value').

Comment: I did not have any documentation for my suggestion so I made it a comment..

Comment: @mplungjan: Thank you for your comment as well. I upgraded it!

Answer (score 1):

Either "Plug in that value" or "plug that value into" are fine depending on the rest of the sentence, but not "Plug in that value into".

Comment: Removing the *in* could fix the sentence.

Comment: @Noah That's what I said.